# Pass CAT command as argument to function

Tags: bash, function, cat

I'm trying to write a very simple bash script that modifies a number of files, and I'm outputting the results of each command to a log as a check whether the command was completed successfully. Everything appears to be working except I can't pass CAT with variables to my script -- I keep getting a `cat: >>: No such file or directory` error.

```
#! /bin/bash

file1="./file1"
file2="./file2"

check () {
  if ( $1 > /dev/null ) then
    echo "     $1 : completed" | tee -a log
    return 0;
  else
    echo "ERR> $1 : command failed" | tee -a log
    return 1;
  fi
}

check "cp $file1 $file1.bak"            # this works fine
check "sed -i s/text/newtext/g $file1" # this works, too
check "cat $file1 >> $file2"          # this does not work
```

I've tried any number of combinations of quoting the command. The only way that I can get it to work is by using the following:

```
check $(cat $file1 >> $file2)
```

However, this does not pass the command itself to `check` only the return value, so `$1` in function `check` carries `/dev/null` and not the command performed, which is not the particular behaviour I want.

Just for completeness, the `log` file looks like:

```
     cp ./file1 ./file1.bak : completed
     sed -i s/text/newtext/g ./file1 : completed
ERR> cat ./file1 >> ./file2 : command failed
```

I'm sure the solution is rather simple, but it has eluded me for a few hours and no amount of Google searches has yielded any help. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the I/O redirection in your `cat` command is not being interpreted as I/O redirection but rather as a simple argument to the `cat` command.  It's not `cat` so much as the I/O redirection that is causing grief.  Trying a pipeline would also give you problems.

Options available to remedy this include:

```
check "cp $file1 $file2" # Use copy instead of cat and I/O redirection; clobbers file2

check "eval cat $file1 >> $file2" # Use eval to handle I/O redirection, piping, etc
```

If either `$file1` or `$file2` contains shell special characters, the `eval` option is dangerous.

The `cp` command substitutes something that works without needing I/O redirection.  You could even use a (microscopic) shell script to handle the job — where your script executes the shell script, and the shell script handles the redirection:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec cat ${1:?} >> ${2:?}
```

This generates a default error message if either argument 1 or 2 is missing (but doesn't object to extra arguments).

Comment: `$file1` and `$file2` contain paths and filenames. Could using, for example, `eval cat ./mypath/rm ./mypath/file` result in evaluating `rm ./mypath/file`?

Comment: The primary problem characters in the file names would be things like spaces, dollar signs, back-ticks; things which have special meanings to the shell.  If `file1="./mypath/rm"` and `file2="./mypath/file"`, then there's essentially no way to run into problems.  If you're in charge of the names (no user input into what they are), you'll probably be OK.  If you have to deal with user input, you have to be worried about them providing `file1='$(rm -fr / >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo Hi)'` as the file name; this can do a lot of damage to your machine.

Comment: `cp` would be fine if you could append and not replace. For the micro-shell script, could you still capture the command syntax for output to a log? And possibly run the other commands (`cp`, `sed`) through the same script, passing each command as a variable?

Comment: If the micro-script is called `cap` (for concatenate/append), then you would write `check "cap $file1 $file2"` and your `check` function would log the command as the `cap` command instead of `cat`. Since there's no I/O redirection in the string passed to `check`, there'd be no need to use `eval`.  Whether that 'works for you' is your call.  Unless you're calling this hundreds of times a minute, there's unlikely to be a real efficiency problem.

Comment: Instead of a micro-script, you can just define another shell function (as in my edited answer).  It still "feels weird" though.

Comment: @torek: In some ways, the whole 'logging' process is a bit weird; it would be possible to use the shell's built-in `set -x` code to trace execution, redirecting standard error to the appropriate place. I've got a few scripts that do this sort of tracking, and it always ends up being a bit messy (and usually ends up using `eval`). As to your 'use another function' suggestion; that probably works too — I tend not to use functions (as much as I could/should), but that's more ancient history and a dislike of cluttering the shell with too many functions or environment variables than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: the approach I first tried below doesn't quite work.  There's another trick that can rescue this, even without resorting to bash magic, but it's getting ugly.

---

The `>>` redirection occurs at the wrong level, in this case.  You wind up asking `cat` to read `./file`, then a file named `>>`, then `./file2`.  To get the redirection to occur you'll need to do it elsewhere (see below), or invoke `eval`.

I'd recommend *not* using `eval`, but instead, rejiggering the logic of function `check` instead.  You can redirect `check` at the top level, e.g.,:

```
check() {
    if "$@"; then
        echo "     $@ : completed" | tee -a log
        return 0
    fi
    echo "ERR> $@ : failed, status $?" | tee -a log
    return 1
}

check cp "$file1" "$file.bak"                     # doesn't print anything
check sed -i s/text/newtext/g "$file1" >/dev/null # does print, so >/dev/null
check cat "$file1" >> "$file2"
```

(The double quotes here in the invocations of `check` are in case `file1` and/or `file2` ever acquire meta-characters like `*` or `;`, or white space, etc.)

**EDIT**: as @cdm and @rici note, this fails for the append-to-file cases, because `check`'s output is redirected even for the `tee` command.  Again the redirection is happening at the wrong level.  It's possible to fix this by adding another level of indirection:

```
append_to_file() {
    local fname
    fname="$1"
    shift
    "$@" >> "$fname"
}

check cp "$file1" "$file.bak"
check append_to_file /dev/null sed -e s/text/newtext/g "$file1"
check append_to_file "$file2" cat "$file1"
```

Now, though, the completed and failure messages log `append_to_file` at the front, which is really pretty klunky.  I think I'd go back to `eval` instead.

Comment: `check cat "$file1" >> "$file2"` will not log anything if the command fails because the path specified by `$file2` doesn't exist or can't be written to. That's because bash tries to open `"$file2"` for append *before* it executes the command, since it has to redirect `stdout` before it does the `exec`. When that fails, it never executes `check` so no logging is performed.

Comment: @rici: True, except that "doesn't exist" is not a problem if the file can be created.  (So this fails if the file does not exist and the directory is not write-able, or if the file does exist and is not write-able.)

Comment: if there is a directory in the path which doesn't exist, it will fail. But that's not the point: the point is that it fails *without being logged*.

Comment: I've been exploring @torek's suggestion; there is still a misdirection in the `cat` command as the command line (`cat ./file1 : completed`) is not only being appended to the `log` file but also to `$file2`, in both cases only up to `>>`.

Comment: @cdm: Good point; of course it will. I don't think this approach will work.

Comment: @cdm: Ah, yes, this quite ruins the whole idea.